# Group Theory (Sylow p-subgroups questions)

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $GL_n\mathbb{F}_p$ be the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with entries coming from $\mathbb{F_p}=\{0, 1, ..., p-1\}$ and with group operation multiplication of matrices. (We are writing $\mathbb{F_p}$ for this object to not confuse it with $\mathbb{Z_p}$, the $group$ of integers modulo $p$ with the operation $+$ modulo $p$; $\mathbb{F_p}$ is the $field$ of order $p$, where $p$ is prime.)

a) Show that $|GL_n\mathbb{F_p}|=(p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2)...(p^n-p^{n-1})$

Hint: You need to use the invertible nature of the matrices when its columns are linearly independent.

b) Show that $p \cdot p^2 \cdot ...\cdot p^{n-1}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing the order of $GL_n\mathbb{F_p}$

c) Deduce that the matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ with $(a_{ij})=0$ when $i<j$ and $a_{ii}=1$ form a Sylow p-subgroup of $GL_n\mathbb{F_p}$.

I gather that we can think of $\mathbb{F_p}$ in the same way we think about $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. When we have vectors with entires in $\mathbb{F_p}$ we can talk about linear independence of such matrices in the usual way, and matrix multiplication as usual and them being invertible as usual, blah blah blah...

Just getting to grip with Sylow's theorems and this sort of algebra.

Comment: That's three questions. Which one do you want to ask?

Comment: Any of them would be great. Should I not have put all three under one question?

Comment: For part (a): The first column can't be the zero vector; that gives you $p^n-1$ possibilities (since there are $p^n$ vectors with $n$ entries). The second column can't be in the linear span of the first column, which has $|\mathbb{F}_p|=p$ elements; that means you have $p^n-p$ possibilities for the second column. The third column can't be in the linear span of the first two; that subspace has... etc.

Comment: For part (b): use part (a). For part (c), verify that those matrices form a group, and count how many such matrices there are.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't see how to use part (a) in part (b). Is it something to do with Lagrange's theorem? And for part (c) can I simply check the group axioms on the matrices to see if it's a group.

Comment: @Penguinking14: Part (a) gives you an *explicit* formula for the number of elements. Can't you figure out the largest power of $p$ that divides this product? Hint: the largest power of $p$ that divides $ab$ is the product of the largest power of $p$ that divides $a$ and the largest power of $p$ that divides $b$.

Comment: My bad, I get it now, part (b) isn't that hard. For part (c) do I need to do anything extra to prove it's not just a group but also a Sylow p-subgroup of GLnFp?

Comment: @Penguinking14: You need to check that it has the correct order to be a Sylow $p$-subgroup; that’s why you are doing part (b), so you know how big those Sylow subgroups are, and you can verify that these are of the correct size.